# systemctl enable not working

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, systemd

Why does systemctl give no error message when  all the following attempts to enable or reenable netctl-auto@wlp3s0.service manifestly fail

```
~ $ systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled  
autovt@.service                            enabled          
getty@.service                             enabled          
systemd-fsck-root.service                  enabled-runtime  
remote-fs.target                           enabled          
~ $ sudo systemctl enable netctl-auto@wlp3s0.service   
~ $ systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled  
autovt@.service                            enabled          
getty@.service                             enabled          
systemd-fsck-root.service                  enabled-runtime  
remote-fs.target                           enabled          
~ $   sudo systemctl unmask netctl-auto@wlp3s0.service   
~ $   sudo systemctl reenable netctl-auto@wlp3s0.service   
Removed /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/netctl-auto@wlp3s0.service.  
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/netctl-auto@wlp3s0.service â†’ /usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl-auto@.service.  
~ $ systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled  
autovt@.service                            enabled          
getty@.service                             enabled          
systemd-fsck-root.service                  enabled-runtime  
remote-fs.target                           enabled          
~ $   sudo systemctl start netctl-auto@wlp3s0.service   
~ $ systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled  
autovt@.service                            enabled          
getty@.service                             enabled          
systemd-fsck-root.service                  enabled-runtime  
remote-fs.target                           enabled
```

The symlink created above refers to /usr/lib/systemd/system/netctl-auto@.service, which has these characteristics.

```
~ $ systemctl -a list-unit-files|grep netctl@.service  
netctl@.service                            static           
~ $ systemctl status netctl@.service  
Failed to get properties: Unit name netctl@.service is neither a valid invocati>  
~ $ sudo systemctl enable netctl@.service  
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy, Also, Alias  
settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for template units).  
**This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.**  
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:  
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's  
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.  
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has  
   a requirement dependency on it.  
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,  
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).  
4) In case of template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some  
   instance name specified.
```

Comment: But `netctl@.service` is not the same thing as `netctl-auto@.service`.

Comment: Right, but I think netctl-auto is a sub-system of netctl, and as it is in a symlink created by the system, I assumed it knew what it was doing.